# Has there ever been official pornographic media for an anime and/or manga series?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

I've been wondering about this for a while now. With how perverted some anime and manga are without ever crossing into pornographic content territory, were there ever any anime or manga with **official** pornographic media? Example: a little spinoff series of sorts of a regular anime/manga, with one or two episodes focusing on characters bumping uglies mostly. Bonus points if those "interactions" are officially canon.

Obviously, I'm not talking about something like Dragon Ball or Pokémon. That's just weird. I'm talking about anime and manga that are already adult oriented, which already have some light sexual elements or sexual overtones, where it would make sense for official pornographic content to exist.

I wouldn't be surprised if some companies already tried to squeeze some extra bucks from the more fanatic and perverted parts of the fanbase, while those uninterested in the content never have to see it if they don't want to.

I'm specifically talking about series(es?) that started out relatively non-perverted and whose main source stayed relatively tame - no intercourse is ever shown directly, but it could be implied. VNs that had perverted elements and were turned into anime/manga later do not count, but feel free to give some examples if you want to.

Comment: Most of manga that kinda like that is seinen...

Comment: @Gagantous If I understand the question correctly, I don't think there are many (I can't even recall any). The question seems to be "given an existing adult-oriented (but not explicit) work, there's an official hentai (or, explicit adult anime/manga) for it". I know seinen or ladies have adult-oriented romance, but I don't recall any that got official hentai.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you specifically asking about canon anime that are not tagged as hentai, having an canon series/ova/ect that is tagged as such? Also, are you disqualifying anime that were originally tagged as hentai and then later had a non-H adaption made? or does it have to be from non-H to H?

Comment: @JesseBarnett It has to be non-H to H. I'd imagine it would be easier for H to go to non-H than it is for non-H to go to H, hence why I'm curious for those specifically, wondering if non-H would gain or lose something from going H (really digging those abbreviations btw, makes things much easier, thanks for that :P)

Comment: Have a look at Princess Lover ?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the question as posed:  **largely, no.**  A work will make its intentions clear up front.

An anime or manga creator typically shies away from playing both sides, and will either commit to having their work be either tame or explicit.  That is to say, on one side, you'll have a work which is largely non-sexual and then has a few fanservice scenes [(for example, *The Electric Tale of Pikachu*)](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/The_Electric_Tale_of_Pikachu#Controversy_and_censorship), or work which is largely dedicated to pornography (examples omitted, for...reasons.)

To call some attention to a point made here:

> I wouldn't be surprised if some companies already tried to squeeze some extra bucks from the more fanatic and perverted parts of the fanbase, while those uninterested in the content never have to see it if they don't want to.

[*Dakimakura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakimakura), and [some of the designs you get with them](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2016/12/17-2/konosuba-my-teen-romantic-comedy-snafu-and-girlish-number-hug-pillows-ready-to-warm-up-the-winter), *largely* fill this void, even if the work is non-pornographic (as is the example prior with *KonoSuba* and *Oregairu*).  The same is true of other fan-oriented goods, like [figurines in various poses and attire](https://www.crunchyroll.com/store/p/194491/Rem-Wedding-Version-Non-Scale-Figure-ReZERO-Starting-Life-in-Another-World-), and sales of certain articles of clothing.

(I think at one point, *Sailor Moon* had released a [line of lingerie](http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2014/08/20-1/second-wave-of-official-sailor-moon-lingerie-teased).  I neither judge nor ask questions.)

I do want to highlight though, that this is likely being driven *largely* by the companies and not necessarily the creator themselves.  I don't deny that some element of the creator's participation is necessary, though.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, sorta. There is [*Aki Sora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aki_Sora). However, I wouldn't really call it tame. Quoting the "Reception" section,

> Chris Beveridge commends the OVA for "good character designs, some good eroticism". He further comments, "While we get a fair bit of upper body nudity, there’s no genitalia involved for those that are looking for that aspect of it ... it’s not hiding the sex, but it’s also straddling the line in a way to try to appeal to more people while not going all hardcore."

While the *Aki Sora* Wikipedia page doesn't actually say if the manga was hentai, the [*A Wish of my Sister*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wish_of_my_Sister#See_also) (Wikipedia, **NSFW warning**) under "See Also" says:

> Aki Sora - another hentai manga by the same author, which characters (Sora and Aki) are similar in appearance and actions with Keisuke and his older sister

And while I haven't read it myself, a friend who suggested it to me

> (for the shoujo-ai/yuri elements in it at the end)

said that the graphical nature of the intercourse isn't like that if what you would expect from H doujin and in fact you don't actually see genitalia much like the OVA.

However, neither one of these are a spin-off like the first example you suggest. Generally, a hentai adaptation comes from an adult source like [Beat Angel Escalayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_Angel_Escalayer).

In the opposite way, a Visual Novel with adult content generally gets it removed such as with *Fate/Stay Night*, *Utawarerumono* and *Tears to Tiara*, though all of these had all-ages equivalent releases and future releases weren't eroge (*Fate/Extra*, *Utawarerumono: Mask of Deception*, *Tears to Tiara 2*). The closest I have ever seen is in the *Tsukihime* which had H scenes<sup>1</sup> in it with the heroines yet in the anime which adapts only the Arcueid Route

> shows a scene where it's implied that Tohno Shiki and Arcueid had intercourse (Arcueid is covered but you can tell she's naked) and its place in the plot lines up to when the H scene involves them would take place.

But with series like *Bleach* and *Naruto* where it's evident that characters must have had intercourse to have their children (ie, Naruto and Hinata having Boruto and Himawari), as these series are generally aimed at younger readers/viewership, the creation of hentai anime/manga to bridge these gaps for when children were conceived can't be marketed to the same demographics of the original works.

---

<sup>1: I am unsure if this is retained functionality or new functionality, but the installer of the Mirror Moon English Patch for *Tsukihime* had an option to remove the H scene which was also in-game. The same trigger was also found in-game in its sequel *Kagetsu Tohya*.</sup>

Comment: "but with series like Bleach and Naruto where it's evident that characters must have had intercourse to have their children, ... creation of hentai anime/manga ... can't be marketed to the same demographics of the original works." Why not? The Naruto and Bleach fans must have been adult, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

**Kite -> Mezzo Forte**

Technically it is, **Hentai (official) -> Hentai (official)**

So, it **doesn't** perfectly follow your flow of **Anime (softcore official) -> Hentai (official)**

But, in the case of **Kite**, you can approximate the equation to **Anime (softcore official) -> Hentai (official)** depending on what version of Kite you saw.

- Original Version (16+) : **Anime (softcore official) -> Hentai (official)**
- Director's Cut (18+)   : **Hentai (official) -> Hentai (official)**

Long story short, there is not **yet** any perfect case for this,
**Anime (softcore official) -> Hentai (official)**

Comment: *Kite* and *Mezzo Forte* aren't really related in any way except for a character cameo appearance, but their sequels, *Kite Liberator* and *Mezzo DSA*, are softcore, so they have a reverse flow of **Hentai (official) -> Anime (softcore official)**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can count series that were very ecchi in the beginning but turned into completely explicit porn in the later volumes, like Masou Gakuen HxH, Magika no Kenshi to Shoukan Maou, and Shinmai Maou no Testament.

Comment: I think one possible issue is determining what is really considered "pornographic", since even non-explicit sex doesn't always make the work as pornographic media/hentai, or the equivalent R-18 in Japan ...